# mac zsh cannot find any folder

Tags: macos, zsh

I typed "export $GOPATH=/Users/myusername/Desktop/test" into my mac terminal. Then I got an error "zsh: /Users/myusername/Desktop/test not found". I had a folder named test in the Desktop. I tried rebooting my mac but still got the same error.

This is the result of "echo $PATH":
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands

Anyone what's happening?

Comment: What do you get when you do `cd /Users/myusername/Desktop` and `ls -al`? Doesn't `test` show-up?

Comment: cd and ls work perfectly fine.

Comment: `$` is used to dereference a variable. You do not use it when _defining_ variables. Try `export GOPATH=...` without the `$`.

Comment: Please format the code part of your question [properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), so that we can see exactly what commands you have used.

Answer (score 1):

*Anyone what's happening?*

Since the variable `GOPATH` was not defined and therefore empty, the command

```
export $GOPATH=/Users/myusername/Desktop/test
```

expanded to

```
export =/Users/myusername/Desktop/test
```

In zsh `=SOMETHING` expands to the absolute path of the executable *SOMETHING* (you can try it with `echo =ls`), and if the *SOMETHING* part is already a path, zsh only checks that the executable exists. In your case, `/Users/myusername/Desktop/test` is not an executable file, and this resulted in the error message.

Of course all the mess was started by the typo in your `export` statement. This kind of errors can be caught if you put into your ~/.zshrc the command

```
set -u
```

This causes an error message whenever you try to expand an uninitialized variable. With this setting, you would get at least a helpful error message (in your case, the message would have been *zsh: GOLANG: parameter not set*), and you would see the reason for the error.